# PDO Select Statement with MVC

Tags: php, pdo

"
im working on a small MVC website and ive run into a small problem. I want to be able to populate the HTML select dropdown with data pulled from my database. Ive the Select statement in my Model class, the standard HTML stuff in my View class and my controller is currently empty as im a little confused as to what im supposed to add there.

Code works fine with no errors. However, my view renders twice.

Here is my code:

Model:

```
<?php
require_once('../Controller/config.php');

class AppCalc 
{
    public $dbconn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->dbconn = $db;
    }

    public function fillDropdown(){
        $stmt = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT Appliance FROM appliances");
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}

?>
```

View:

```
<div id="appForm">

    <form id="applianceCalc">
        Typical Appliance: 
        <select name="appliances">
            <?php foreach($appliances as $appliance): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $appliance['Appliance']; ?>">
                <?php echo $appliance['Appliance']; ?>
            </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <br>

        Power Consumption:
        <input type="text"></input>
        <br>


        Hours of use per day:
        <input type="text"></input>
        <br>
    </div>
        <input type="submit" name="btn-calcApp" value="Calculate"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="btn-calRes" value="Reset"></input>

    </form>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
   <?php
require_once('../Model/applianceModel.php');
require_once('../Tool/DrawTool.php'); 

$newCalc = new AppCalc();
// instantiate drawing tool
$draw = new DrawTool();
// parse (render) appliance view
$renderedView = $draw->render('../View/applianceCalculator.php', array(
    'appliances' => $newCalc->fillDropdown()
));

echo $renderedView;

?>
```

My config file:

```
<?php
class Database
{   
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "energychecker";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    public $dbconn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->dbconn = null;    
        try
        {
            $this->dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->dbconn;
    }
}
?>
```

This is the table im using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appliances` (
  `AppId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Appliance` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `PowerConsumption` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AppId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

This is what i currently see:
http://i66.tinypic.com/30b31mx.jpg

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model function `fillDropdown` should return array of fetched rows, e.g.:

```
public function fillDropdown(){
    $stmt = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT Appliance FROM appliances");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Then, you have to somehow pass data to the View. I recommend to build some class to render views. This can be very simple:

```
class DrawTool
{        
    public function render($viewPath, array $context = array())
    {
        // start output buffering
        ob_start();

        // make variables with $key => value pairs from $context associative array
        // context will be gone after method execution thanks to variable scope
        extract($context);

        // render View
        include $viewPath;

        // return rendered View as string data type
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Now, if You have your Draw class to render Views you can simply draw View with code below, in Controller:

```
require_once('../Model/applianceModel.php');
require_once('../Tool/DrawTool.php'); // or wherever else you plan to put this class

$newCalc = new AppCalc();
// instantiate drawing tool
$draw = new DrawTool();
// parse (render) appliance view
$renderedView = $draw->render('../View/applianceView.php', array(
    'appliances' => $newCalc->fillDropdown()
));

echo $renderedView;
```

And, inside View file:

```
<div id="appForm">

    <form id="applianceCalc">
        Typical Appliance: 
        <select name="appliances">
            <?php foreach($appliances as $appliance): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $appliance['id']; ?>">
                <?php echo $appliance['name']; ?>
            </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <br>

        Power Consumption:
        <input type="text"></input>
        <br>


        Hours of use per day:
        <input type="text"></input>
        <br>
    </div>
        <input type="submit" name="btn-calcApp" value="Calculate"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="btn-calRes" value="Reset"></input>
</form>
</div>
```

In View file you just traverse `$appliances` array (fetched rows), where single `$appliance` is one row represented by array with e.g. `id` and `name` keys.

And a couple of tips at the end:

- do not end pure PHP file with `?>` tag, because any character (most common is white character) after that tag will trigger error with already sent headers, if you wish to set some headers **before** outputting content
- think about some value check at `fillDropdown` method, becuase method `$stmt->fetchAll()` can also return *false* on failure

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! Really appreciate it. However, im now getting an error: `Notice: Undefined variable: dbconn` This was after calling my controller class in the view. I have no also edited my original post to include the table im working with.

Comment: Right, instead of `$stmt = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT Appliance FROM appliances");` should be `$stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("SELECT Appliance FROM appliances");`

Comment: Hi that seems to have worked. However the HTML form prints twice. Once with the populated dropdown and once without. Ive edited my original post

Comment: Your controller echo'es the **whole** View file, so you propably echo it again somewhere further, i think. Is your Controller entry point file (something like index.php)?

Comment: In my view file I've required the controller. Should I remove it?

Comment: **Yes.** Your controller render View and all needed data are passed by Controller into View.

Comment: Thanks! If i wanted to use another select statement in the same page. Would i call it in the same controller?

Comment: Yes. You should add another variable to the `$context` array, and use it in View file the same way.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. Would you be able to give a quick example?